# Openshift Custom Cartridge with Python 3.4

Tags: python, django, openshift, cartridge

Hi there I was recently developing an application on openshift.

I used the Python 3.3 Cartridge together with Django. And there is the problem. Because of the "old" version of python I get some exceptions. (Which is indeed a problem with the python version, because i tested it with python 3.3.2 on my local computer.)

My question is know is it possible to make an custom cartridge with pyhton 3.4? Or even update the existing python cartridge?

If yes, how does it work?

Comment: No, you don't have root access to install new python version, that will be a request to OpenShift team to include higher python versions

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to create a custom cartridge that has python 3.4.  You would need to ssh into a gear on OpenShift Online (or use a compatible local RHEL or CentOS installation) to compile python 3.4 and it's dependencies, then you can use the Cartridge Developers Guide (https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html) to create a cartridge that you can install it with.

You can also add it as a request at https://openshift.uservoice.com and get other users to vote on it.